# Update an entity and only overwrite non-null values (without a dynamic query)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I want to update an existing entity by handing an "incomplete" instance of that entity to the `JpaRepository`. By incomplete i mean that only the values i want to change are set and the other values are `null`. Now if i would do that, all `null` values would be saved as `null` too and therefore overwrite the values i want to keep.

I thought about loading the entity from the database first and somehow merge the changes into that loaded object and saving it again, but there must be a better approach.

My entity:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Location {

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    private UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();

    @Column
    @NotEmpty
    private String title;

    @Column
    @NotEmpty
    private String description;
...
```

My repository:

```
@Repository
public interface LocationRepository extends JpaRepository<Location, UUID>, LocationFilterFragment, JpaSpecificationExecutor {

    Optional<Location> findLocationById(UUID id);
...
```

I use the standard `repo.save(location)` method by the way.

**Update:** One way could be to use a dynamic query / criteria query, but i am looking for something more convenient and less error prone.

It would be enough to show me the right direction, because I do not know exactly what to look for. Thanks in advance!

Comment: how many fields are you updating?

Comment: I want that to be dynamic. For example if i only want to update the title, i set title to the new value and have the other values on `null`. Or if i want to update the description too, i set it to a non-null value too. Except for the ID of course.

Comment: i'm not sure you can do something like that dynamically until you write query

Comment: This seems so obvious to me that there has to be an easier way. :D

Comment: you can wait until someone post the best answer

Comment: what about criteria query update? https://thoughts-on-java.org/criteria-updatedelete-easy-way-to/

Comment: That's what I meant with dynamic queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first approach would be: don't merge your incomplete object. If you call `save` on your repository (which translates to a `merge` on an entityManager) Hibernate treats this as a current state, and will update all values.

I would proceed with the following:

- find the entity you want to change by id
- set the values you want to change by copying them from your "incomplete object"

Remember that these 2 steps must be performed in one transaction. When exiting the transaction scope, hibernate will rely on its dirty checking mechanism and update the entity (no `merge` call needed) In this approach your "incomplete object" does not have to be an entity, it is never persisted.

Note that by default, all fields will be sent in the update query (but now unchanged fields are not null, they reflect the previous state of the dB) if you want only dirty fields to be part of your query, learn about `@DynamicUpdate`

Another note: if you go down your custom jpql or criteria API update, you have the benefit of one select not executed. On the downside, Hibernate isn’t aware of the changes and doesn’t update its caches.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you have any idea how I can "set the values you want to change by copying them from your "incomplete object"", without having to if/else every single attribute and setting it manually?

Comment: To be frank, everything I think of is either over-engineered or sacrifices type safety. It deserves a separate question, though.

Comment: If your "incomplete object" comes from some controller, than it was already created with reflection, so maybe following that is not that bad. I remember using JPA metamodel in one project, but I would be hesitant to recommend it to your case (as over-engineered)